# R Subsetting text from a comma seperated column in a data-frame

Tags: r, string

I have a data.frame with a column that looks like that:

```
diagnosis
F.31.2,A.43.2,R.45.2,F.43.1
```

I want to somehow split this column into two colums with one containing all the values with F and one for all the other values, resulting in two columns in a df that looks like that.

```
F             other
F.31.2,F43.1  A.43.2,R.45.2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next `tidyverse` approach. You can separate the rows by `,` and then create a group according to the pattern in order to reshape to wide and obtain the expected result:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(diagnosis='F.31.2,A.43.2,R.45.2,F.43.1',stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
new <- df %>% separate_rows(diagnosis,sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(Group=ifelse(grepl('F',diagnosis),'F','Other')) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fn = toString,names_from=Group,values_from=diagnosis)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  F              Other         
  <chr>          <chr>         
1 F.31.2, F.43.1 A.43.2, R.45.2
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked! It seems to need more steps than I initially thought.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `strsplit` at the commas. Then, using `grep` find indexes of *F*, and select/antiselect them by multiplying by 1 or -1 and `paste` them.

```
tmp <- el(strsplit(d$diagnosis, ","))
res <- lapply(c(1, -1), function(x) paste(tmp[grep("F", tmp)*x], collapse=","))
res <- setNames(as.data.frame(res), c("F", "other"))
res 
#               F         other
# 1 F.31.2,F.43.1 A.43.2,R.45.2
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- setNames(read.table(text="F.31.2,A.43.2,R.45.2,F.43.1"), "diagnosis")
```